# How to use Spring Security login service in React JS component

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I'm currently following a Spring Boot login tutorial, my goal is to use the backend logic in combination with a React frontend component.

I've implemented a registration service and a registration rest controller (REST API) in the Spring Boot backend. User input from the registration form can now be pushed into the database with an axios post method. The registration part is working well in the front- and backend, the login however works in the backend on localhost:8080 only. I didn't have to implement a login service yet, everything worked fine after implementing the registration logic, because the login logic/service is offered by Spring Security by default apparently.

Now it's time to implement the login confirmation in the frontend with React JS, but I'm not quite sure, how to implement the login service or whether I need to do that at all. I don't know how to define a method to confirm the login form user input after comparing it to existing data in the database.

**This is how I would give it a shot (not sure how to exactly implement it though):**

1. Implement a get method inside the submit handler method of the React login component via axios to fetch existing user account data from the database
2. Grant access, if the login form user input is identical with one of the saved user account records from the database

RegistrationService.java:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationService {

    private final BenutzerkontoService benutzerkontoService;
    private final EmailValidator emailValidator;
    private final ConfirmationTokenService confirmationTokenService;
    private final EmailSender emailSender;

    public String register(RegistrationRequest request) {
        // check whether email is valid
        boolean isValidEmail = emailValidator.test(request.getEmail());

        if (!isValidEmail) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Email is not valid");
        }

        String token = benutzerkontoService.signUpUser(
                new Benutzerkonto(
                    request.getEmail(),
                    request.getPasswort(),
                    // TODO: Create logic to differentiate user and authority (consider ui role selection)
                    UserRole.USER
                )
        );

        String link = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/registration/confirm?token=" + token;
        emailSender.send(request.getEmail(), buildEmail(request.getEmail(), link));

        return token;
    }

    @Transactional
    public String confirmToken(String token) {
        ConfirmationToken confirmationToken = confirmationTokenService
                .getToken(token)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Token not found"));
        if (confirmationToken.getConfirmedAt() != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Email already confirmed");
        }

        LocalDateTime expiredAt = confirmationToken.getExpiresAt();

        if (expiredAt.isBefore(LocalDateTime.now())) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Token expired");
        }

        confirmationTokenService.setConfirmedAt(token);
        benutzerkontoService.enableAppUser(confirmationToken.getBenutzerkonto().getEmail());
        return "confirmed";
    }

    private String buildEmail(String name, String link) {
        return "<div style=\"font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;margin:0;color:#0b0c0c\">\n"...
    }


}
```

RegistrationController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/registration")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationController {

    private RegistrationService registrationService;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @PostMapping
    public String register(@RequestBody RegistrationRequest request) {
        return registrationService.register(request);
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @GetMapping(path = "confirm")
    public String confirm(@RequestParam("token") String token) {
        return registrationService.confirmToken(token);
    }
```

}

RegistrationRequest.java

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class RegistrationRequest {
    private final String email;
    private final String passwort;
}
```

Registration.js (React component):

```
function Registration() {

    const email = useRef();
    const password = useRef();
    const passwordValidation = useRef();
    const role = useRef();

    /**
     * This function handles the submission event for the user input inside the registration form.
     *
     * @param event
     */
    function submitHandler(event) {
      
        event.preventDefault();

        const enteredEmail = email.current.value;
        const enteredPassword = password.current.value;
        const enteredPasswordValidation = passwordValidation.current.value;
        const enteredRole = role.current.value;

        // This object contains the user input
        const registrationData = {
            email: enteredEmail,
            passwort: enteredPassword,

        }
        axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/registration",registrationData).then(res => {
            console.log(res)
        })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }

    return (
        <div className={"register"} id={"picBack"}>
            <div id={"picFilter"}>
                <div id={"regText"}>
                    <p className="h2">Please Register</p>
                </div>
                <div id={"regContainer"}>
                    <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                        <Form.Group>
                            <Form.Label htmlFor={"exampleInputEmail1"}>Email address</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type={"e-mail"} id={"exampleInputEmail1"} aria-describedby={"emailHelp"} placeholder={"Enter email"} ref={email}></Form.Control>
                            <small id={"emailHelp"} className={"form-text light-text"}>We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group>
                            <Form.Label htmlFor={"inputPassword5"}>Password</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type={"password"} id={"inputPassword5"} placeholder={"Password"} aria-describedby={"passwordHelpBlock"} ref={password}></Form.Control>
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group>
                            <Form.Label htmlFor={"inputPassword5"}>Password Confirmation</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type={"password"} id={"inputPassword5"} placeholder={"Password"} aria-describedby={"passwordHelpBlock"} ref={passwordValidation}></Form.Control>
                            <Form.Text>
                                Your password must be 8-20 characters long, contain letters and numbers, and
                                must not contain spaces, special characters, or emoji.
                            </Form.Text>
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group>
                            <Form.Label>Role</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Select ref={role}>
                                <option value={"student"}>Student</option>
                                <option value={"lecturer"}>Lecturer</option>
                            </Form.Select>
                        </Form.Group><br/><br/>
                        <Button variant={"danger"} type={"submit"}>Register</Button>
                    </Form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Registration
```

Comment: #1 Did you use spring security for ssr apps(old)? #2 Do you know the http endpoints of spring security? #3 Do you  need just the login or the logout and other session features?

Comment: 1. Yes, I suppose. I've used it for the user authentication in the backend.
2. No, I don't.
3. Login and logout should be included.